# How to update MySQL database from a HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to create a Point of sale application for android using PhoneGap, So I have created front end using HTML5,JS,CSS

I'm using MySQL as backend and PHP for server side scripting.I've created login for a user and selecting shops for the purchase successfully.Now am confused in the database update

My scenario is I have following tables in mysql

Table : **pos_master**

```
CREATE TABLE `ordermaster` (
  `ordid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `wid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `repid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `orddate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `acid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isdone` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ordid`)
)
```

Table : **pos_details**

```
CREATE TABLE `orderdet` (
  `ordid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) NOT NULL
)
```

and I have created a table in my html page to enter products and its qty it looks like this(https://jsfiddle.net/egpqbzuc/)

till this everything is fine.Now I need to update these entries in aforementioned tables

its like `pos_master` update first(I have stored values for `wid,repid,acid,orddate,isdone` in my html) and the second table should update with the value from the corresponding entry in `ordid` and the values in my html table to second table `pos_details`.How to do this within a transaction block so that I can *commit* or *roll back* my sql task

Answer (score -1):

If you are using PDO, you can check this out: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php. Similar solutions can be found in PHP documentation.
And at last, you can also use pure sql:
$db->query('START TRANSACTION;')
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Comment: @rimboche, it is NOT advisable to issue SQL queries from mobile devices. This MAY subject your DB to injection attacks. For security purposes, you are better off running the SQL on the server, and make and [RPC-style call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call). This is a suggestion.